# Load Data into Hive from Flat files or existing database

Tags: hadoop, hive, business-objects

We are setting up Hadoop and Hive in our organization.
Also we will be having the sample data created by data generator tool. The data will be around 1 TB.
My question is - i have to load that data into Hive and Hadoop. What is the process i need to follow for this?

Also we will be having HBase installed with Hadoop.
We need to create the same database design which is right now there in SQL Server..But using Hive. Cz after this data loaded into hive we want to use the Business Objects 4.1 as a front end to create the Reports.
The challage is to load the sample data into the Hive..
Please help me as we want to do all the things asap.

Comment: And what is holding you back from doing this?

Comment: This is not a programming question.  What is your specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

- First ingest your data in HDFS
- Use Hive external tables, pointing to the location where you ingested the data i.e. your hdfs directory.
- You are all set to query the data from the tables you created in Hive.
- Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For the first case you need to put data in hdfs.

1. Transport your data file(s) to a client node (app node)
2. put your files en distribute file system (hdfs dfs -put ... )
3. create an external Table pointing the hdfs directory in which you uploaded those files. Your data have been structure of some way. For instance delimited by semicolon symbol.
4. Now you can operate over the data with sql queries.

For the second case you can create another hive table (using HBaseStorageHandler , https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration) and load from the first table with Insert statement.

I hope this can help you.